# HTML: Submit multiple forms with one submissions ONLY IF that form is checked

Tags: conditional-statements, submission

So I have a page with multiple input forms; is it possible to submit all these forms AT THE SAME TIME with one submit button? Also, each form has its own checkbox, and I want it so that if it is checked, it will NOT submit the data within that form to the PHP script. If the checkbox IS checked, I want it to submit the data within that form. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: I figured that it was; any idea for how to do so?

Comment: That's your job... Show us what you've done to this point. You only asked if it was possible in your OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use AJAX or join all forms in one, which u will submit.

Comment: I guess I'll be combining all those forms into one then, since I don't know ajax. :/